# Showing that the diagonal of $X\times X$ is transversal to the graph of $f$. (1.5.10 Guillemin and Pollack)

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology, transversality

The question and its answer is given below:

> [image]

But I am wondering, is it also correct if I showed that graph f is transversal to diagonal of $X\times X$?

Also, I can not understand the general idea he using in his proof in the last paragraph, could anyone explain this for me please?

**EDIT:**

These are the exercises referred to:

> [image]
>   [image]

Thank you!

Comment: Your first questions seems odd, it is the exact same question in the title and exactly what is done within the solution. If you are asking whether $\Delta_X \pitchfork \Gamma(f)$ is the same as $\Gamma(f) \pitchfork \Delta_X$, then yes, this is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this comes a bit late, but still...

This is a potential answer for the 1.5.9 from Guillemin & Pollack's Differential Topology

1.5.9: Suppose that $+1$ is eigenvalue of A

For $W$ to be transversal to $\triangle$ we would need
\begin{equation}
\forall (x,x) \in W\cap\triangle : T_{(x,x)}W + T_{(x,x)}\triangle = T_{(x,x)}{(V\times V)}
\end{equation}
Now $T_{(x,x)}\triangle$ is the diagonal of $T_xV\times T_xV$ *(cf. the 1.2.10 from Guillemin & Pollack)*,
V is a vector space, so $T_xV = V$ and hence $T_{(x,x)}\triangle = \triangle$

Also $T_{(x,A(x))}W $ is the graph of $d_xA : T_xV \rightarrow T_xV$ *(cf. the 1.2.11 from Guillemin & Pollack)*. A is linear, so $\forall x \in V : d_xA = A$. Moreover, if $x \in W \cap \triangle$ then $A(x) = x$ and hence $T_{(x,x)}W = T_{(x,A(x))}W = W$. So the condition for $W$ and $\triangle$ to be transversal becomes
\begin{equation}
W + \triangle = V\times V
\end{equation}

But it is clear that $V\times V$ contains points that $W + \triangle$ does not. For instance, if $v \in V$ is a non-zero vector such that $Av = v$ then $(v,0)$ is not included in $W + \triangle$.

Now suppose that $+1$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$. Then $W \cap \triangle = \{ (v,v) : $ for $v \in V$ such that $Av = v \} =  \{ (0,0) \} $ . Then $\dim(W+\triangle) = \dim(W) +  \dim(\triangle) - \dim(W \cap \triangle) = \dim(V \times V)$ so $W + \triangle = V \times V$

So "$+1$ not eigenvalue of $A$" implies $W \pitchfork \triangle $

And hence $W \pitchfork \triangle $ if and only if $+1$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$